# Can Elasticsearch suggest range for query on number fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example I have a list of person with have `age` property.
On my search page, I allow user to query this list base on the range of age:

```
"mus" : {
    "range" : {
        "age" : { "from" : 60, "to" : 80 }
    }
},
```

Let say the above query return 0 result (since my list include only person from 20 to 50), do ES support any method to return the suggestion for this range query (in this case [20, 50])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `histogram` aggregation in order to retrieve these counts.

```
{
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "age": {
            "from": 60,
            "to": 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ages": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "age",
        "interval": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query would return:

- all documents whose `age` field is between 60 and 80
- the number of documents whose `age` field is within 10-year buckets, i.e.

  - for age between 10 and 20: 4 documents (fake number)
  - for age between 20 and 30: 6 documents (fake number)
  - for age between 30 and 40: 12 documents (fake number)
  - for age between 40 and 50: 2 documents (fake number)
  - ...

Comment: Awesome, great it helped!!